# Customizing Registration form in Visual Studio 2013 using Asp.net Identity (Web Forms)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity

if we take a look at the following post: [Web Form Text Fields Not straight on ASP Identity Register page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214037/web-form-text-fields-not-straight-on-asp-identity-register-page/26442184#26442184)

In this post, the user managed to add additional fields to the database using Visual Studio 2013 using Asp.net Identity (Web Forms).

Since there is no much documentation about how to accomplish this in Web Forms, could you possibly share some code and let me know how to add 2 texfields such as Firstname and LastName?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good article down here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun

It explains ApplicationUser and ApplicationDbContext implementations of IdentityUser and IdentityDbContext in MVC but you can apply all to your Web Forms project too.

Comment: I am new to this forum and I have posted an answer to you but not sure if a comment was better. Thanks

Comment: Can you give specifics of the error you encounter when you try to create a user? The code looks right to me.

Comment: There is no error actually. The user is not created. All the form is inside an updatepanel. Do you think that being the lastname and firstname textboxes inside the updatepanel I need to write the code differently? Thank you

Comment: Since you said you manually add the columns to uses table, did you update your EDMX file after adding columns to the database?

Comment: Maybe this is what I m missing. Where can I find my EDMX file and do you have suggestion on how to update it?

Comment: Did you create your project via new project wizard on Visual Studio? If so it doesn't generate an EDMX file for you. It's implemented as code-first. If that's the case, what you need to do is undo the change you did on database, go to Package Manager Console on Visual Studio and type Enable-Migrations. After that, you need to add a new migration with default values by typing Add-Migration "MigrationName" command. Then enter command Update-Database.

After you are done, you should add new properties to ApplicationUser and add another migration via console. Update-Database again.

Comment: Thank you so much Omer Cinbat, your help has been really fundamental. Now everything works perfectly.

Comment: Sure :) Sorry if I didn't yet. Unfortunately I have no sufficient points to upvote but I of course marked as answered your last answer. Thank you again and have a nice day